# Trying to learn how to implement Semaphores in C in a controlled loop

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, fork, semaphore

I am trying to understand how to use a semaphore. I've been writing code where one process execs off multiple child processes in a controlled loop. I want to implement children to access resources using semaphore locks. Whenever I write something, I get a Segmentation Fault (Core dumped) issue. Whenever I search for some help, I find an implementation without a good explanation. Here is what I wrote for now

in the Main program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/ipc.h>
#include<sys/shm.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>    

#define key 0x10101010

int main(int * argc, char * argv[])
{
    int i,count=0;
    pid_t pid;
    int status;
    int *scount;
    int shmid;
    shmid = shmget(key,sizeof(int),IPC_CREAT | 0666);
    if(shmid == -1)
    {
        perror("\n SHM Error");
    }
    scount = shmat(shmid,0,0); 
    scount = 0;

    for(i = 0;i<10;i++)
    {
        pid = fork();
        if(pid < 0){
            perror("\nFork error\n");
        }
        else if(pid == 0){
            execlp("./child","./child",NULL);
            exit(0);
        }

    }
    for(i =0;i<10;i++)
    {
        if(pid > 0){
            wait(pid);
            //printf("\nI am parent and my PID %d",getppid());
        }
    }
    printf("\nTotal number of processes forked are %d\n",*scount);

sem_unlink("./semakey123");
return 0;
}
```

and in the child process:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/ipc.h>
#include<sys/shm.h>
#include<semaphore.h>

#define key 0x10101010
#define semkey 0x91919191
int main(int *argc, char *argv[])
{
    int shmid,semid;
    int *count;
    sem_t *sem;
    sem = sem_open("./semakey123",IPC_CREAT |0666);
    sem_init(sem,0,0);
    if(sem = SEM_FAILED)
     perror("\n Semaphore not opened");
    shmid = shmget(key,sizeof(int), IPC_CREAT | 0666);
    if(shmid ==-1)
    {
        perror("\n SHM Error");
    }
    else printf("\n SHM attached to CHild");
    count = shmat(shmid,0,0);
    printf("\nEntering Critical section");
    sem_wait(sem);
    sleep(3);
    *count+=1;
    printf("\n Count: %d\n",*count);
    sleep(2);
    printf("\nExiting critical section");
    sem_post(sem);
    return 0;
}
```

When I comment semaphore related code, that Count in shared memory goes beyond the limit. The program terminates without going to an infinite loop, but still at the core dump occurs. With the semaphore code uncommented, I get a Segmentation fault right away. Any help is appreciated.

P.S: I am not a beginner in programming, but I am a beginner in systems programming.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have been confusing with the *System V semaphore*, because you are trying to setting up a *Posix semaphore* (http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sem_open.3.html) with modes defined for System V ones (http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/semget.2.html).
Than be carefoul using pointers... after mapping shared memory to your *scount* variable, you are doing scount = 0. I suppose you would have wanted to initialize it to 0, by doing *scount=0.

Let me know if and how you solved :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've been busy and didn't check it. I'll go through the links and get back to you.